# Как правильно прописать путь при подключении модели

Tags: php, yii2

Модель лежит по следующему пути

```
use app\..\..\text.domen-domen.ru\backend\models\Client;
```

ругается на text.domen-domen.ru
Как правильно прописать путь?

Answer (score 0):

В указании namespace не должно быть никаких символов, за исключением нижнего подчёркивания (хотя нижнее подчёркивание при автолоадинге может сыграть тоже злую шутку, так `\namespace\package_name\Class_Name` будет искаться по пути `/path/to/project/lib/vendor/namespace/package_name/Class/Name.php`